# Android using setAnimationListener in array adapter

Tags: android, android-animation

i want to create animation for listView items such as rotate or move. now in my array adapter i want to after touch on item i can be set animation for that. in this code i have array adapter but i can not using `setAnimationListener` in `fill` method.

summarized **MainActivity:**

```
public class ActivityMainView extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main_view_container);

        /* SAVE current context */
        G.context = getBaseContext();

        mSlidingMenu = getSlidingMenu();
        mSlidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shape_sliding_menu_shadow);
        mSlidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.sliding_menu_shadow_width);
        mSlidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.sliding_menu_offset);
        mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        mSlidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        mSlidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.15f);

        UiFiller uiFiller = new UiFiller(mSlidingMenu);

        uiFiller.laySlideMenuSmsReceive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showSelectedItem(M.MIS_ReciveSMS);
            }
        });

    private void showSelectedItem(int index) {
        Fragment mFragment = null;

        if (index == mLastMenuItemSelected)
            return;

        FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastViewFragment != null) {
            fts.remove(mLastViewFragment);

        }
        switch (index) {
            case M.MIS_ReciveSMS:
                mFragment = new FragmentSmsReceive();
                txtSelectedSlideTitle.setText(UC.getResourcesText(R.string.slide_menu_sms_receive));
                break;
        }
        fts.replace(R.id.smsViewFragment, mFragment);
        fts.commit();
        mLastMenuItemSelected = index;
        mSlidingMenu.showContent(true);
        mLastViewFragment = mFragment;
    }

}
```

Summarized `FragmentSmsReceive()`:

```
public class FragmentSmsReceive extends Fragment {
    private static final Boolean        DEBUG = true;
    public ArrayAdapter                 adapter;
    private ArrayList<StructReceiveSms> receiveSmsArray;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        G.currentActivity = FragmentSmsReceive.this.getActivity();
        adapter = new AdapterReceiveSms(G.smsArray);
    }
}
```

Summarized AdapterReceiveSms **ArrayAdapter:**

```
    public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<StructReceiveSms> adapter, final StructReceiveSms item, final int position) {
        uiFiller.txtSmsReceiveItemContactName.setText(item.mobile);
        uiFiller.txtSmsReceiveItemDate.setText(item.mDate);
        uiFiller.txtSmsReceiveItemSmsBody.setText(item.smsBody);
        animMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(G.currentActivity, R.anim.move);

        // set animation listener
        Animation.AnimationListener listener = (AnimationListener) G.context;
        animMove.setAnimationListener(listener);
        uiFiller.layoutRoot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uiFiller.layoutRoot.startAnimation(animMove);
            }
        });
    }
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vHolder;

        StructReceiveSms item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sms_receive_item, parent, false);
            vHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(vHolder);
        } else {
            vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        vHolder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Error:

```
The method setAnimationListener(Animation.AnimationListener) in the type Animation is not applicable for the arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `G.currentActivity` is referencing the parent activity of the ListView. Whatever you're assigning to `setAnimationListener` needs to implement the [Animation.AnimationListener interface.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

Make sure that your activity is implementing this interface. Once you do this, you can cast your context within the adapter to this interface class and then assign the reference to the interface.  Something like the following. NOTE: this is off the top of my head and untested.

```
Animation.AnimationListener listener = (AnimationListener) context;
animMove.setAnimationListener(listener);
```

Comment: thanks sir. my adapter is set into Fragment and after `implements AnimatorListener`  i get this error now: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.view.animation.Animation$AnimationListener`.Post UPDATED

Comment: That's not going to work as the context is coming from the Activity and not the fragment.

Comment: how to fix now? how to use context into ArrayAdapter?

Comment: What are you doing inside the fragment?  Can this code be moved into either the adapter or the parent activity?  You can certainly get to it in your fragment. It just gets a bit more complicated .

Comment: unfortunately i can not move that. `G.context` set in to main activity and i'm call Fragment from that after set `G.context = getBaseContext();` my fragment now `implements AnimatorListener` and array adapter is other class.

Comment: So, then you're going to have to move the AnimationListener implementation into the parent Activity. Inside there, grab the reference to your fragment and call a method there that does what you need it to do. Like I said, more complicated.  If you post the code from the AnimationListener implementation, I may be able to help more.